# `netstat` command in WSL return empty list

Tags: windows-10, netstat, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I install python and start `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in windows WSL. But the command `netstat -an` return an empty list. And of course i can't visit the url http://127.0.0.1:8000 in windows browser.

Furthermore, any commands which expose a port like ssh are not working.

Here is my windows version:

- Windows 10 1703 15063.608

Here is the screenshots:

[image]

Comment: Might want to patch your system

Comment: @Ramhound sorry i don't understand :( Should i update my system to insider preview?

Comment: No; You are missing the patch that was released on September 12th

Comment: @Ramhound The update histories show that last installed patch is KB4038788 was released on September 12th. But unfortunately it's still not work. Need I reinstall the WSL?

Comment: If you have that patch installed then your build is 15063.608 not 15063.540

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I forgot to update the question description. As you say, os version is 15063.608. But the problem is still not solved.

Comment: @Ramhound Should I reinstall the WSL?

Comment: I'm able to browse to the served files from the Windows _host_, but `netstat` does not yield anything either on Ubuntu or on Windows.

Answer (score 9):

It is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2249) that `netstat` does not currently work under WSL.

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
alias netstat='/mnt/c/Windows/System32/netstat.exe'
netstat
```

Answer (score 3):

As OrangeDog link says, the netstat native linux does not work under WSL (v1).

However in the [GitHub comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2249#issuecomment-477230161) there is a workaround (nice or ugly, I don't know): you can use the netstat.exe instead (I am also surprised that windows executables `.exe` runs on Linux).

Then in my WSL (v1) I was able to execute something like this:

```
netstat.exe -an | grep -i "listen" | grep -v "\[::\]" | grep 1616
```

A solution using the real native Linux executable would certainly be better but in the meantime this workaround does the job.